# Applying CSS to one page only

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I need to apply CSS to the  masthead on all pages except the homepage in the Wordpress Twenty Sixteen theme. At the moment I am manually doing it like:

```
.page-id-24 #masthead {
padding: 5%;
background-image: url(...);
background-size: 1400px 500px;
height: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.page-id-14 #masthead {
padding: 5%;
background-image: url(...);
background-size: 1400px 500px;
height: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Is there any way I can write something like `#masthead not:(home) {...}` to drastically speed up the process and change the masthead on all pages except the homepage.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: [Yes there is. `:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: So how would I do that in this case

Comment: why don't you just not include the masthead div on the homepage (or rename it? Not rocket science...

Comment: `#masthead:not(.home-page-masthead) { /* styles */ }`

Comment: i can't find where to edit the html on homepage on wordpress twenty sixteen theme so am trying to get around that

Comment: thank you turnip :)

Comment: #masthead:not(.home-page-masthead) { /* styles */ } isn't working :(

Comment: All of the mastheads simply have the (id?) #masthead so I don't know if I can do it this way

Comment: could i not use #masthead:not(:home)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange!

It's a good thing you've mentioned "Twenty Sixteen" as your theme. I was able to pull up a demo of your theme on wordpress.org and identify an acceptable selector for your purposes. Please consult the following:

```
body:not(.home) #masthead { /* Stylish */}
```

This selector should work out for you.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZGmLV

The way the :not() selector works is that it's treated as a **pseudo class** that can take in a simple selector to negate. In our case, we're looking for an element (more specifically, your `<header>` element) with the "masthead" ID that's *only on the home page*. Additionally, we're using this selector to **exclude** from our style.

.

Suggested Further Reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: No problem. Please acknowledge that the question has been solved so that others may take advantage of this solution, too! :)